# How do I extract words from a list that start with "A" in PYTHON I?

Tags: python

The directions say "Use the following initializer list:

w = ["Algorithm", "Logic", "Filter", "Software", "Network", "Parameters", "Analyze", "Algorithm", "Functionality", "Viruses"]
Write a loop to print the words that start with "A".

Sample Run
Algorithm
Analyze
Algorithm"

I tried to do it with the following code:

```
w = ["Algorithm", "Logic", "Filter", "Software", "Network", "Parameters", "Analyze", "Algorithm", "Functionality", "Viruses"]

for i in range(len(w)):
     if (i[0] == "a" or i[0] == "A"):
          print(w[i])
```

but I keep getting the error "Line 4: TypeError: 'int' does not support indexing"

pls help

Comment: `if w[i][0].lower() == "a": print(w[i])`

Comment: I think the `for` loop should be - `for i in w`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to get the word out of the list and instead were trying to get the first character of the index (i), which obviously doesn't work.

```
w = ["Algorithm", "Logic", "Filter", "Software", "Network", "Parameters", "Analyze", "Algorithm", "Functionality", "Viruses"]

for i in range(len(w)):
     if (w[i][0] == "a" or w[i][0] == "A"):
          print(w[i])
```

However a more "pythonic" way of iterating over a list is as follows:

```
for word in w:
     if (word[0] == "a" or word[0] == "A"):
          print(word)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a list comprehension for this

```
>>> [word for word in w if word[0].upper() == 'A']
['Algorithm', 'Analyze', 'Algorithm']
```

If you want to be case-specific (i.e. do not match both `'a'` and `'A'`) you can remove the `.upper()`

Answer (score 1):

> How do I extract words from a list that start with “A”

[`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) does exactly that:

> Return True if string starts with the prefix, otherwise return False. prefix can also be a tuple of prefixes to look for. With optional start, test string beginning at that position. With optional end, stop comparing string at that position.

```
>>> [word for word in w if word.startswith("A")]
['Algorithm', 'Analyze', 'Algorithm']
```

Answer (score 1):

Another easier approach:

```
for word in w:
    if word.startswith("A"):
        print(word)
```